# Get html text from an url that has errors in the load with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the html text from a website using HTML Agility Pack, but it has an error in the load and is only giving me a part of the html text... is there any way to get the whole text avoiding errors with that DLL o any other solution.

[image: Error]

Comment: What are you talking about? HAP will not give "part" of the source.  It sounds like you actually want to evaluate Javascript.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to extract? What is the url ?

Comment: Hi Veverke, i want to get the exchange rate that is in the line that says "Estados Unidos de América       Dólar de N.A.       x,xxx" from this url: http://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/stats/TC-Contable.as

Comment: Navigating to the link you shared gives an error. I could only navigate to sbs.gob.pe. Please provide a working link.

Comment: Sorry the link was http://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/stats/TC-Contable.asp .... I think that this website is loading two times...:S